# где можно найти хорошие уроки по SceneBuilder?

Tags: java

Создать саму обертку легко, а где можно научиться связыванию логики и этой обертки? Может учебники есть, или видеоуроки... Заранее спасибо.

Comment: [Вот](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm)

Comment: @not a Programmer от души!

Answer (score 3):

1. [Java FX и Scene Builder уроки от Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm).
2. [Хорошие видео-уроки по Java FX и Scene Builder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v96cc7Mk-v0&index=7&list=PLwwk4BHih4fi1rkT7XAHrwya3Qjuo63AK).